# How to display a Google Document inline image on HTML page?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Is it possible to select an inserted inline image in a Google Document and show it on HTML page ?

Comment: Please provide some more information! What do you mean with selecting? What do you expect?

Comment: I mean with selecting : `paragraph.getChild(0).asInlineImage()`

Comment: You can download the inline image as a BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' using the method [getAs(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image#getAs(String)). Then you can include that file in HTML page. Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there anyway other than downloading (maybe send it to Google Drive) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also [getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image#getBlob()) and then insert a file in Drive folder using [createFile(BlobSource)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(BlobSource))

Hope that helps!